# Jquery Mouseleave and e.target or e.relatedTarget

Tags: jquery, mouseleave

When I move from li.food to #news-wrap, mouseleave fires.

This does not work:

```
$('#news-wrap').hide();
$('li.food').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('#news-wrap').show();
});
$('li.food').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('#news-wrap')) {
        $('#news-wrap').hide();
    }
});
```

Nor does this:

```
$('#news-wrap').hide();
$('li.food').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('#news-wrap').show();
});
$('li.food').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    if(e.relatedTarget.id != 'news-wrap') $('#news-wrap').hide();    
});
```

Comment: why do you need to capture mouseleve?just capture mouseenter and hide all div then show the needed div

Comment: I want #news-wrap to only show when the mouse is on li.food or #news-wrap.

Comment: can you add a fiddle?

Comment: I can see this working, mouse over food class to show, mouse then to news wrap to keep it shown/else it hides again? https://jsbin.com/hotitowefa/edit?html,css,js,console,output   what is the intended functionality here

Comment: That is what I want to do, but the code is still not working for me for some reason.  li.food is in boot strap nav bar. #news-wrap is a row of images with text under them. i want #news-wrap to show up when hovering on li.food and to be able to move from li.food to #news-wrap. i tried doing, li.food > ul > li.news-wrap but that still does not work. mouseleave keeps firing no matter what as i go from li.food to #news-wrap

Comment: Why don't you sue simple css ? Like `li.food:hover ~ #news-wrap{ display : block }`

Comment: I could not figure out how to make it show as a full col-sm-12 across the screen div as a dropdown from the navbar. when i tried to do it with css it was not showing centered on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used CSS instead of jquery.

```
li.food:hover {
 #news-wrap { 
   display : block 
 }
}
```

See this [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/8tphdeor/7/) as comparison.